# How do I remove the time portion from a epoch conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, epoch, to-date

I am trying to get ride of the time portion of a conversion from epoch time to human readable form. Here is what the data output looks like currently:

| Ticket Number | Created | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14111487 | 2/1/2023 1:36 AM | 2/15/2023 6:00 AM |
| 14116522 | 2/1/2023 11:18 PM | 2/15/2023 6:00 AM |
| 14116477 | 2/1/2023 11:23 PM | 2/17/2023 9:25 PM |
| 14116425 | 2/1/2023 10:47 PM | 2/15/2023 5:05 PM |

and here is what I want it to look like:

| Ticket Number | Created | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14111487 | 2/1/2023 | 2/15/2023 |
| 14116522 | 2/1/2023 | 2/15/2023 |
| 14116477 | 2/1/2023 | 2/17/2023 |
| 14116425 | 2/1/2023 | 2/15/2023 |

How the heck do I get rid of the time within my query, I don't need it. Here is the relevant parts of the query that I'm using:

```
SELECT
TICKET.TICK_NUM AS "Ticket Number",
TO_DATE('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + (DATECREATED / 86400) AS "Created", 
TO_DATE('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + (FIXEDTIME / 86400) AS "Completed"
FROM TICKET
WHERE 
TICKET.DATECREATED BETWEEN 1675209600 and 1677196800;
```

I am using Oracle Developer 21.4.3

Comment: ```TRUNC(date)```

Comment: If you truncate it then you will still see the time, based on what your session's NLS settings seem to be from what you see now; but it will be midnight, so '0:00 AM' I guess. Oracle dates *always* have a time. If you don't want to see it then either change your NLS settings which will affect all dates, or use `to_char()` to format them with just the date elements. (Also, epoch time is UTC, so you might want to convert to your time zone - before truncating *8-)

Comment: TRUNC() only works if your client  (Oracle Developer) has built-in logic to auto-hide the 00:00:00. Other clients would probably show you the 00:00:00. So for universal display, change it to a string via TO_CHAR() and a specific date map { e.g. TO_CHAR(completed,'MM/DD/YYYY')  }

Comment: How would I reword either the created or completion to change to TO_CHAR?

Comment: PS. If I should be using "TO_CHAR" isn't that going to convert the date to a string? I ask because another part of my query subtracts completed from creation to get an age at completion. That subtraction wont work if I am converting to a string right?

Comment: You should do any date arithmetic as dates, before any string conversion. You use TO_CHAR at the end to convert it to a string exclusively for desired display in your client. And I should note that usually folks don't do that. They are okay with whatever format their client wants to show, or they configure a default date format in the client and let their client do the conversion by setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT and implicitly adding a TO_CHAR() around the fetched column. That's what my favorite client (DBArtisan) does. You really don't want to be having to mess with this for every query with a date

Comment: I think I need to redo this post anew cause I should have included the arithmetic part cause that is what's causing problems. I got the TRUNC and TO_CHAR figured out but together they can't do simple subtraction cause 1-15 is 14 not 13.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the time component to midnight then use `FLOOR` or `TRUNC` before adding to the date to round the number down to be a whole day:

```sql
SELECT TICKET.TICK_NUM AS "Ticket Number",
       DATE '1970-01-01' + FLOOR(DATECREATED / 86400) AS "Created", 
       DATE '1970-01-01' + FLOOR(FIXEDTIME / 86400) AS "Completed"
FROM   TICKET
WHERE  TICKET.DATECREATED BETWEEN 1675209600 and 1677196800;
```

```sql
SELECT TICKET.TICK_NUM AS "Ticket Number",
       DATE '1970-01-01' + TRUNC(DATECREATED / 86400) AS "Created", 
       DATE '1970-01-01' + TRUNC(FIXEDTIME / 86400) AS "Completed"
FROM   TICKET
WHERE  TICKET.DATECREATED BETWEEN 1675209600 and 1677196800;
```

Or `TRUNC`ate the date after adding the epoch time:

```sql
SELECT TICKET.TICK_NUM AS "Ticket Number",
       TRUNC(DATE '1970-01-01' + DATECREATED / 86400) AS "Created", 
       TRUNC(DATE '1970-01-01' + FIXEDTIME / 86400) AS "Completed"
FROM   TICKET
WHERE  TICKET.DATECREATED BETWEEN 1675209600 and 1677196800;
```

Or, if you just want to format it as a date string to display it without the time component then use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TICKET.TICK_NUM AS "Ticket Number",
       TO_CHAR(DATE '1970-01-01' + DATECREATED / 86400, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "Created", 
       TO_CHAR(DATE '1970-01-01' + FIXEDTIME / 86400, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "Completed"
FROM   TICKET
WHERE  TICKET.DATECREATED BETWEEN 1675209600 and 1677196800;
```